# reduced homologies of shifted complexes

Tags: homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

I am trying to understand dimension of reduced homologies of shifted complexes. Lemma 2.15 of the book Combinatorial commutative algebra by Miller and Sturmfels explains it. But the last part of the proof confuses me. It may have some misprints, I suppose. Is there any other reference for this statement?
(In the proof, is it true in general that $\tilde{C_i}(k*\Delta)=\tilde{C_i}(\Gamma)$ and hence $dim_K\tilde{H}_{i+1}(k*\Delta, \Gamma)=\#\{F\in k*\Delta: dim\ F=i+1, F\notin \Gamma\}$? If so, then by the discussion given in the proof the latter set is equal to  $\{k\cup F: \text{$F$ an $i$-facet of $\Delta$}, k\cup \Delta\notin \Gamma\}$. Hence the lemma is proved and there is no need for the discussion in the last paragraph (about minimal near-cone etc.). What is wrong in the above argument?
Lemma 2.15: Fix a shifted simplicial complex $\Gamma$ on $1,\ldots,k$, and let $\Delta\subseteq \Gamma$ consists of the faces of $\Gamma$ not having $k$ as a vertex. Then $\dim_K\tilde{H}_i(\Gamma;K)$ equals the number of dimension $i$ facets $F$ of $\Delta$ such that $F\cup k$ is not a face of $\Gamma$.

Comment: Could you state the lemma for those who do not have that book?

Comment: Sure, here it is: Fix a shifted simplicial complex $\Gamma$ on $1,\ldots, k$, and let $\Delta\subset \Gamma$ consists of the faces of $\Gamma$ not having $k$ as a vertex. Then $dim_K \tilde{H}_i(\Gamma; K)$ equals the number of dimension $i$ facets $F$ of $\Delta$ such that $F\cup k$ is not a face of $\Gamma$.

Comment: This statement is proved in Theorem 4.3 of  "An extended Euler-Poincare theorem " by Bjorner and Kalai. But the proof is different from the one in the above mentioned book.

Comment: I will be grateful if someone helps.